# Passing std::promise object to a function via direct function call

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am learning the `std::promise` and `std::future` in C++. I wrote one simple program to calculate the multiplication of two numbers.

```
void product(std::promise<int> intPromise, int a, int b)
{
    intPromise.set_value(a * b);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 10;
    std::promise<int> prodPromise;
    std::future<int> prodResult = prodPromise.get_future();
    // std::thread t{product, std::move(prodPromise), a, b};
    product(std::move(prodPromise), a, b);
    std::cout << "20*10= " << prodResult.get() << std::endl;
    // t.join();
}
```

In the above code if I invoke the `product` function using threads it's working fine. But if I invoke the function using direct function call I am getting the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I added some logs to check the problem. I am getting the error while setting the value (`set_value`) in the function `product`. Is there anything I missed in the code?

Comment: Which compiler and platform? And how do you compile this code?

Comment: I am running the code in Ubuntu machine.I tried in online compilers also but the result is the same

Comment: Please be more specific. Ubuntu version, compiler version and compiler invocation command line. I can't reproduce this on my Kubuntu 19.04 machine. Do you add `-pthread` option? If not, add it and try again.

Comment: the result of the command ```g++ --version```  is ```g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0```

Comment: Try adding `-pthread`.

Comment: Do I need to use -pthread because I am not using threads(commented the code)?

Comment: @Evg thanks man It's working now.

Comment: I added an explanation why it compiles but produces an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile this code, even if don't use `std::thread` explicitly, you still have to add `-pthread` command line option, because internally `std::promise` and `std::future` depend on the `pthread` library.

Without `-pthread` on my machine I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
```

With `-pthread`:

```
20*10 = 200
```

---

> My doubt is if `std::promise` using `std::thread` then it should throw some compilation or linkage error right?

Very good question. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321743).

Comment: yes, It's working now. My doubt is if ```std::promise``` using ```std::thread``` then it should throw some compilation or linkage error right?